# how to paste numbers with thousand separator from excel to sqldeveloper table editor

Tags: oracle

There's data exported to excel:

```
MS_ID   STARTDATETIME
3 704 285   09.11.2014 11:29:25
3 704 285   09.11.2014 11:29:25
```

I want to paste it back to Oracle using sqldeveloper table data editor.
For date column I do

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm.dd.yyyy HH24:mi:ss';
```

But I'm also getting:

```
INSERT INTO "PPB"."CDRGPRS" (MS_ID, STARTDATETIME) VALUES ('3 704 285', TO_DATE('09.11.2014 11:29:25', 'mm.dd.yyyy HH24:mi:ss'))
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The SQL above is generated by sqldeveloper.

There's no `NLS_NUMBER_FORMAT`. How to make Oracle format and parse numbers with spaces as thousand separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote this macro and put it to `Personal.xlsb`

```
Sub nospace()

Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "0"

Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", _
    SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[`TO_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140) allows you to specify whatever separators you want using `nls_numeric_characters`.

```
SQL> select to_number( '100 123,23'
  2                   , '999G999G999D99'
  3                   , 'nls_numeric_characters = '', '''
  4                     ) as no
  5    from dual;

        NO
----------
 100123.23
```

`G` is the [number format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) corresponding to the separator, which is the second option of your `nls_numeric_characters`.

If you want to convert it into a number improperly you can [`REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) the spaces:

```
SQL> select to_number(replace( '100 12323', ' ')) as no
  2    from dual;

NO
--------
10012323
```

Comment: > The SQL above is generated by sqldeveloper.

Comment: Yes, and? You're attempting to put a character into a number column. SQL Developer doesn't know that you haven't formatted the numbers as numbers so you're going to have to stop relying on SQL Developer to generate statements for you.